# Django one to many field dont render duplicates

Tags: django, django-models, one-to-many, django-filter

Lets suppose I have this model:

```
| Name | Email | Level
  John     X       1
 Martin    Y       2
 Jorge     C       1
```

Level is a one to many field, and when I render the levels only , it render 1 , 2 and 1 again, is there a way to not render the duplicate ones, but in the template ? I need to do the coding in the template , not the views.
Any idea ?

Comment: Take a look on [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup)

Answer (score 0):

Your object should have a property named Level.  You should be able to iterate the object's/entity's Level property because it is a list.  You can iterate Level just like any collection the the Django template.  Hope this helps.